# Get data from php-foreach-loop to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I have searched very long for a solution to this problem but could not find any.

I get data from the database to show some projects on my website. For each project i can click on a pen-symbol to edit the name of the project. I´d like to send the date per ajax request, but always get the data of the first project. If i try for example to edit the name of the second project "test", i get the data of the first project "blubb"

What i have tried:
- Used classes not Id´s 
[Call Ajax function from PHP foreach with form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376998/call-ajax-function-from-php-foreach-with-form) 
- Used  $this 
[Get Ajax variable from the PHP foreach loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145838/get-ajax-variable-from-the-php-foreach-loops)

My code lookes like this (simplified):

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {

//here are the problems, i only get the value of the first project
      var new_project_name = $('.new_project_name').val(); 
      var old_project_name = $('.old_project_name').val();


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/edit/edit.php",
        data: {
          old_project_name: old_project_name,
          new_project_name: new_project_name,
          name: name
        },

      }).

      done(function(response) {
        blabla

      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```

```html
<?php foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY position, id desc') as $row) { $name = $row['name']; ?>

<div class="rename">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Projektname:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="new_project_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
      </td>
      <input type="text" class="old_project_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" hidden>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Umbenennen">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `$('.new_project_name')` will return a collection of everything having class `new_project_name`. I doubt what calling `#val` function on collection is intended to return. To achieve what you want, you should iterate the collection for changes.

Comment: you can use `closest` in jquery to take the corresponding input value OR you can use `id` to differentiate and take the corresponding input value

Comment: @.Siva.G : I tried to use closest like this: var new_project_name = $(this).closest('.new_project_name').val(); But this doesent seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could pass the id of the project to ajax and update the new value. For that you just need to pass the id of the element.

### HTML

```
  <input type="text" class="new_project_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" rel="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

### jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
      var parentObj = $(this).closest('.rename');
      var id = parentObj.find(' .new_project_name').attr('rel');
      var project_name = parentObj.find(' .new_project_name').val();


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/edit/edit.php",
        data: {
          project_name : project_name ,
          id:id
        },

      }).

      done(function(response) {
        blabla

      });
    });
  });
```

### See the Fiddle and check console

http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/2caukhvo/11/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried like you said but firebug tells me, that he gets the name of the first project -> project_name : blubb

Comment: Check My Fiddle and accept answer if it's worth for you

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved the problem. I tried for so many hours without success.